# es6 with axios login user and get respons

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am a newbie at using es6 js, using babel, axios and es6 trying to login user and get a response from a PHP file and all I need is return the response pass it to a callback function. When login is a console logged I get undefined but I want to get access to the data returned just for references.

### account.js

```
 export class Account{
        constructor(){

        }
        methodGet(method,url,inputData,callback){
            axios({
                method:method,
                url:url,
                data: {
                    logindata: inputData
                }
            })
            .then(response=>{callback(response)});
        }

        login(formdata){
            this.methodGet('get','user/logs/login.php',formdata,function (params) {
                let dataParam = params.data;
                return dataParam;
            });
        }
    }
```

### app.js

```
    import { Account } from "./classes/account.js";
    let account = new Account();

    let form  = document.getElementById('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit',event=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        let formdata = new FormData(this);
        console.log(account.login(formdata));
    },true);
```

Comment: You are mixing callbacks and Promises.  Pick one paradigm and stick with it.

Comment: I don't see `console.log` in your example. It's unclear where you expect which value.

Comment: You are `console.log`ing the value returned from `login()`, which is `undefined`

Comment: Make yourself clear with what are callback and promise first, and also learn how sync/async functions work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been there man, it happens with almost all of us. I would suggest you to go understand the basics of promises. Believe me it's one of the most important concept for async operations in JS, it will help you a lot.

I've done few changes in your, please try this.

account.js

```
export class Account{
            constructor(){

            }
            methodGet(method,url,inputData){
                return axios({
                    method:method,
                    url:url,
                    data: {
                        logindata: inputData
                    }
                })
            }

            login(formdata){
                return this.methodGet('get','user/logs/login.php',formdata)
            }
        }
```

app.js

```
 import { Account } from "./classes/account.js";
    let account = new Account();

    let form  = document.getElementById('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit',event=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        let formdata = new FormData(this);
        account.login(formdata).then((response)=>{console.log(response.data)})
    },true);
```

Now let me explain what's happening. Whenever you make a request, it's an async task, so axios will return you a promise. A promise will have states (`pending`, `resolved`, `rejected`). After sending the request the promise returned by the axios will have state pending until response is got. If response is successful the then the state will go to resolve(`then`), or else reject(`catch`).

So only when you will have your response back, the promise state will go to resolve and using `then` you can access your response, if the state of the promise in pending you will get `undefined` because you literally don't have the response yet..

Therefore wait till you have response. Then print(`console.log`) it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks man realy appriciate thats what i am studying now promises and callbacks

Comment: will it work if (new Promise ) is left out.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on it.

Comment: ok I just decided to work with XMLHttpRequest its easy creating a promise chain... thanks

Comment: well if it helps. good luck.